# remote: hooks/update:11: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitlab

I am trying to commit something onto Gitlab from my Ubuntu Machine, I get the following error.

```
user@user-laptop:$ git push
Username for '*************': *********
Password for '************************': 
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 21.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 69 (delta 48), reused 2 (delta 2)
remote: hooks/update:11: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/android_lollipop_testing
To ***********************************
! [remote rejected] android_lollipop_testing -> android_lollipop_testing (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '***************************'
```

Can some one please explain why is it ? What I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `.git/hooks/update` in your repository: you have an `update` hook that runs checks against the files it's about to receive.  In this case it ran the checks, and it blocked the update (or it crashed itself; I can't really tell).  An `update` hook has to exit 0 to allow the update.  See the relevant chapter in the [official git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#idp25956960), and the [reference manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Some times using HTTP clone will only allow PULL but limit PUSH.
Could clone again through SSH, and

Comment: That was exactly the issue long time back. I changed it to ssh and it was working :-) Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Meet the same problem.
This error message is not clear and it means too many possible root cause.

I found my problem:
I clone the branch with HTTP but not SSH.
So it can pull and report error when push.

After re-clone with SSH, nor more error again.